# Using mongoose lean after saving

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

So I am trying to add a key to a returned `post`. But I can't seem to get `lean()` to work. How can I manipulate the returned post after save?

I was thinking maybe I need to add lean to my `findById` like this `Post.findById(req.params.id).lean().then()`. But that didn't work, plus that only makes the first initial post mutable.  It will say

> post.save is not a function

if I do it like `Post.findById(req.params.id).lean().then()` as well

I want to only return the object about to be sent back to the client, I do not want they key saved in the actual document.

```
 Post.findById(req.params.id)
      .then(post => {
        if (
          post.likes.filter(like => like.user.toString() === req.user.id)
            .length === 0
        ) {
          return res
            .status(400)
            .json({ notliked: "You have not yet liked this post" });
        }

        // Get remove index
        const removeIndex = post.likes
          .map(item => item.user.toString())
          .indexOf(req.user.id);

        // Splice out of array
        post.likes.splice(removeIndex, 1);

        // Save
        post.save().then(post => {  
          post["liked"] = false;  <-------
          res.json(post);
        });
      })
```

*edit*

```
  Post.findById(req.params.id)
      .lean()
      .then(post => {
        if (
          post.likes.filter(like => like.user.toString() === req.user.id)
            .length === 0
        ) {
          return res
            .status(400)
            .json({ notliked: "You have not yet liked this post" });
        }

        // Get remove index
        const removeIndex = post.likes
          .map(item => item.user.toString())
          .indexOf(req.user.id);

        // Splice out of array
        post.likes.splice(removeIndex, 1);
        post["liked"] = false;
        res.json(post);
        // Save
        post.save();
      })
```

gives error

> post.save is not a function

Comment: Do you want to update the documents or returned `liked` true or false for the requested user?

Comment: I want to save the updated document that has the modified array and then mutate post in the response body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this by searching for the `req.user.id` inside the `indexOf` `likes` array

```
Post.findOne({ _id: req.params.id }).lean().then((post) => {
  if (post.likes.indexOf(req.user.id) !== -1) {
    post.isLiked = true
  }
  post.isLiked = false
  res.json(post)
})
```

Far better with the aggregation

```
Post.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "_id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user.id) }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "isLiked": { "$in": [mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user.id), "$likes"] }
  }}
])
```

**EDIT :-** If you want to update document then use update query

```
Post.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: req.params.id },
  { $pull: { likes: { user: req.user.id } }},
  { new: true }
).then((post) => {
  res.json(post)
})
```

**Post Schema for likes**

```
...
    likes: [
        {
          user: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "users"
          }
        }
      ]
...
```

Comment: I edited my question and mutated the `post` before saving and send it back as the response and still get post.save isn't a function.

I will have to look into aggregate, but wanted to use the first method.

Comment: You don't need to use `.save` as you don't want to update the document. Just follow my first query.

Comment: I clarified what I meant in response to your original question. My apologies.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thank you sir. I added my schema so the edit I made makes sense for others.